# Unable to record application running on local host in Internet explorer using JMeter Test script recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to do record a test script using JMeter (version 4) Test Script Recorder for performance testing of my application. After configuring the proxy, The recorder is not recording my application URL running on localhost in Internet Explorer (IE 9). But other URLs are getting recorded in JMeter. I tried to record my application using Chrome which is working fine.I have unchecked the Bypass proxy server for local address in Proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org) to record your script because Firefox allows you to manage proxies and certificates independently of system settings.

Get more information about recording:

- [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder)
- [JMeter Recording Guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to check `Use the same proxy server for all protocols` box in the "Advanced" tab of the Internet Explorer proxy settings and there are no `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, etc. in the "Exceptions"

   [image]
2. Some applications cannot route traffic to a local proxy server so you may need to add a [loopback adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc708322(v=ws.10))

   [image]
3. If you're recording an application which operates over HTTPS protocol you will need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`:

   [image]
4. It doesn't really matter which browser you're using for recording as applications mostly differentiate the browsers basing on [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header so you can record using whatever browser and then change User-Agent string in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to IE9
5. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.0 (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)